# Filling up the row before break coloumn

Tags: javascript, php, image, for-loop, image-gallery

I wonder how to fill up a row of images before breaking. Now with my code I can set how many images I want to display in every row but if I want to fill the rows up and then breaking automatically.[image]

This is "my" code I use:

```
$files = glob("images/*.*", GLOB_BRACE);



foreach ($files as $key => $file) {
 if ($key % 3 == 0) { // change 3 to how many items between rows
     if ($key != 0) { echo '</div>'.PHP_EOL; }
     echo '<div class="row">'.PHP_EOL;
 }
 echo '<div class="column"><img src="'.$file.'" style=width:100% /></div>'.PHP_EOL;

}
 ?>


</div>
```

Code: https://stackoverflow.com/users/661872/lawrence-cherone. Dont really know how to credit

Comment: Please provide the code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: do you try to use flex https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ ?

Comment: My code wouldn't produce the output of your image.

Comment: I have images in a folder named "images"

Comment: This is more of a CSS issue, which you float all images left and then calculate the grid/image size to fit in correctly. Ill put together an example, gimie a sec

Comment: https://jsbin.com/poluvixobi/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Yes but if I have a lot of pictures and dont want to put a specific class on everyone how should I do then?